# Windows 8.1 64-bit, CPU is always on max frequency

Tags: windows-8.1, toshiba-laptop, overheating, cpu-speed

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask such question but why not...

I use a Toshiba laptop with Intel i5-4210U and my operating system is Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. For some months now, my CPU is constantly running at the turbo boost frequency no matter what programs and processes are currently started. The CPU usage and the power plan also don't matter.

When I start IntelProcessor Diagnostic tool, the frequency freezes at 0.78 or 1.7 GHz, but when I for example unplug the laptop from the power supply (or plug in when on battery), the turbo boost starts again... this is ridiculous...

My problem is that the CPU is constantly overheated... around 90° C all the time and the fans are constantly working on full power.

What should I do? Any suggestions will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

90 degrees for laptop is abnormal temperature.

There are few possible reasons for that, including driver, apps, virus, general OS malfunction, and a very thick layer of dust inside the cooling system/vents, heat sink broken or loose, motherboard, RAM, etc.

Before jumping on the idea that there's something wrong with the hardware, please try diagnosing the software side first by trying one of the following:

**1. Please open task manager and try and see 
if there is any application or process/service that is utilizing the CPU to its max 100%.**

> If you find something suspicious, try to kill the process/service and analyze
>   what is it and may be remove it from your computer.
>
> If there are no suspicion applications and or services that utilize
>   the CPU heavily go to step 2

**2. Try booting into Safe Mode and see what's going on with the CPU temperature and Turbo Boost.**

> If results in Safe Mode is the same as before, try installing a fresh
>   OS with all the latest drivers and Windows Updates.
>
> **If none of the above helps, than there's probably something wrong
>   with the hardware and you should investigate in that direction.**

Comment: Actually, I find there are good pointers in this answer. For example, trying a new OS is possible via USB flash drive containing a Linux live or a Windows To Go. By trying a new OS, one can isolate the problem.